# HTTP 403 Forbidden when trying to list pods

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

#### The Problem

I am currently trying to use the Kubernetes Server API Client (Python) in order to access cluster resources.

However, it appears that I am unable to make it work. For some reason, I cannot list pods, even though the applied manifest was configured, and for that matter, correctly:

```bash
$ kubectl auth can-i list pods --as=system:serviceaccount:default:my-service-account
yes
```

```py
import kubernetes as k8s

from kubernetes.client.api.core_api import ApiClient
from kubernetes import client, config

service_account_name = "my-service-account"
SA_TOKEN = "the-token"

# Configure API key authorization: BearerToken
configuration = k8s.client.Configuration(
    host="https://192.168.49.2:8443",
    api_key={"authorization": SA_TOKEN},
    api_key_prefix={"authorization": "Bearer"},
    username=service_account_name,
    discard_unknown_keys=True
)

configuration.verify_ssl = False
configuration.client_side_validation = False

api_client = k8s.client.ApiClient(configuration=configuration)
v1 = k8s.client.CoreV1Api(api_client)

v1.list_namespaced_pod("default")
```

which outputs:

```
ApiException: (401)
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': 'c0ec14f1-80fb-4177-b719-273c76230f6c', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Thu, 24 Aug 2023 09:00:59 GMT', 'Content-Length': '129'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401}
```

I've tried to make a `curl` request manually with the same result:

```bash
$ curl --cert ~/.minikube/ca.crt --key ~/.minikube/ca.key -k \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer $(kubectl get secret my-secret -o jsonpath='{.data.token}')" \
        https://192.168.49.2:8443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods

{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "pods is forbidden: User \"minikubeCA\" cannot list resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"default\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "kind": "pods"
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

#### Kubernetes Manifest

This is the manifest which I am applying to the cluster:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount

metadata:
  name: my-service-account
  namespace: default

secrets:
  - name: my-secret


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret

metadata:
  name: my-secret
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: my-service-account

type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token


---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role

metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: reader-role

rules:
- apiGroups: [""]  # Empty string ("") indicates core API group
  resources: ["pods", "pods/logs"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]


---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding

metadata:
  name: reader-binding
  namespace: default

roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: reader-role

subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: my-service-account
  namespace: default
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you get your `SA_TOKEN` in your Python script, but if the `curl` command is making the exact same request, then the issue comes from the fact you're not `base64` decoding the token after retrieving it from the secret.

To get the token, you should write:

```bash
kubectl get secret my-secret -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 -d
```

instead of:

```bash
kubectl get secret my-secret -o jsonpath='{.data.token}'
```

Notice the `base64 -d` operation.

Then:

```bash
curl -k \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(kubectl get secret my-secret -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 -d)" \
    https://192.168.49.2:8443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods
```

should work as expected:

```
{
  "kind": "PodList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "resourceVersion": "857"
  },
  "items": []
}
```

So, as for your Python script, `SA_TOKEN=$(kubectl get secret my-secret -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 -d) python my_script.py` should also work!